# How is bremsstrahlung justified?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, x-rays

Knowing almost nothing regarding quantum physics, it seems to me impossible to understand the idea of Bremsstrahlung. More specifically, let's say we have an electron moving towards an atom's nucleus.

1. Doesn't the kinetic energy of the electron increase while it moves towards the nucleus, since its velocity increases? Where does this increase come from? I mean which other energy is reduced and why?
2. Don't the other electrons of the atom interact with the bombarding electron?
3. Why is the kinetic energy of the electron eventually reduced causing the emission of x-rays?
4. Why doesn't the bombarding electron revolve around the nucleus?

Comment: Have you searched the internet to find answers? Have you read the "related" questions and answers?

Comment: Seriously, and no offence intended, you **need** to reread the complete idea behind this. https://www.britannica.com/science/bremsstrahlung

Comment: Welcome on Physics SE :) Sorry to say this, but it would be nice if you read a bit into the necessary physics or at least to look up a description of the effect and ask us about what in the explanation you do not understand :|

Comment: - How is bremsstrahlung justified?
- You don't have to justify it, actually, it is the opposite. It is an observable phenomenon, which you have to explain theoretically.

Answer (score 2):

**1** The incoming electron sees a sea of electrons and the electrons orbiting the positive nuclei.
So the incoming  electron  undergoes interaction with the medium that it is entering which results in the electron slowing down and emitting electromagnetic radiation in the gamma ray region.
**2** The incoming electrons do interact with the lattice atoms/ions and in doing so lose energy.
**3** An unbound charged particle which is accelerating (negative in this case) emits electromagnetic radiation.
**4** The incoming electron has too much energy to allow them to be bound to a nucleus.

Answer (score 1):

1. An *ion* and an electron have potential energy. The sum of potential and kinetic energy remain constant bar the energy lost as radiation.
2. It's an ion that interacts with the electron. Often it does not possess electrons. But yes, the presence of a partially ionised ion would modify the interaction.
3. The X-ray energy largely originates from the kinetic energy. Without such losses, the interaction would be non-dissipative and the electron would leave with just as much kinetic energy as it arrived.
4. Bremsstrahlung takes place with free electrons that have energies (keV+) that are a lot higher than the binding energy in most cases. In some cases where the electron energy is low enough, recombination radiation might result if an electron can be captured by heavy nuclei.